# Pandas: Change a specific column name in dataframe having multilevel columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-level

I want to find the way change name of specific column in a multilevel dataframe.

With this data:

```
data = {
    ('A', '1', 'I'): [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
    ('B', '2', 'II'): [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
    ('C', '3', 'I'): [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
    ('D', '4', 'II'): [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
    ('E', '5', 'III'): [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
}

dataDF = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This code not working:

```
dataDF.rename(columns = {('A', '1', 'I'):('Z', '100', 'Z')}, inplace=True)
```

Result:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
    1   2   3   4   5
    I   II  I   II  III
0   1   1   1   1   1
1   2   2   2   2   2
2   3   3   3   3   3
3   4   4   4   4   4
4   5   5   5   5   5
```

And also not:

```
dataDF.columns.values[0] = ('Z', '100', 'Z')
```

Result:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
    1   2   3   4   5
    I   II  I   II  III
0   1   1   1   1   1
1   2   2   2   2   2
2   3   3   3   3   3
3   4   4   4   4   4
4   5   5   5   5   5
```

But with combination of above codes working!!!

```
dataDF.columns.values[0] = ('Z', '100', 'Z')
dataDF.rename(columns = {('A', '1', 'I'):('Z', '100', 'Z')}, inplace=True)
dataDF
```

Result:

```
    Z   B   C   D   E
    100 2   3   4   5
    Z   II  I   II  III
0   1   1   1   1   1
1   2   2   2   2   2
2   3   3   3   3   3
3   4   4   4   4   4
4   5   5   5   5   5
```

Is this bug of Pandas?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is my theory

pandas does not want `pd.Index`s to be mutable.  We can see this if we try to change the first element of the index ourselves

```
dataDF.columns[0] = ('Z', '100', 'Z')
```

> 

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-2c0b76762235> in <module>()
----> 1 dataDF.columns[0] = ('Z', '100', 'Z')
```

> 

```
//anaconda/envs/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   1372 
   1373     def __setitem__(self, key, value):
-> 1374         raise TypeError("Index does not support mutable operations")
   1375 
   1376     def __getitem__(self, key):
```

> 

```
TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations
```

---

But pandas can't control what you do the `values` attribute.

```
dataDF.columns.values[0] = ('Z', '100', 'Z')
```

we see that `dataDF.columns` looks the same, but `dataDF.columns.values` clearly reflects the change.  Unfortunately, `df.columns.values` isn't what shows up on the display of the dataframe.

---

On the other hand, this really does seem like it should work.  The fact that it doesn't feels wrong to me.

```
dataDF.rename(columns={('A', '1', 'I'): ('Z', '100', 'Z')}, inplace=True)
```

I believe the reason this only works after having changed the values, is that `rename` is forcing the reconstruction of the columns by looking at the values.  Since we change the values, it now works.  This is exceptionally kludgy and I don't recommend building a process that relies on this.

---

***my recommendation***

- identify location of column name you want to change
- assign name of column to the array of values
- build new columns from scratch, explicity

---

```
from_col = ('A', '1', 'I')
to_col = ('Z', '100', 'Z')
colloc = dataDF.columns.get_loc(from_col)
cvals = dataDF.columns.values
cvals[colloc] = to_col

dataDF.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cvals.tolist())

dataDF
```

[image: enter code here]

Comment: `dataDF.columns.values[0] = ('Z', '100', 'Z')` works for me. Printing `dataDF.columns` afterwards correctly reflects the change. What am I missing here? Did pandas fix this in a newer version?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change it like `DF.columns.levels=[[u'Z', u'B', u'C', u'D', u'E'],[u'5', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'5'],[u'IIIIII', u'II', u'III']]`

Comment: still I am not sure if its bug as your saying.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question as I was myself trying to find the solution for renaming the column names in a data frame with multiple levels. I tried the solution provided by @Dark Matter since it appeared to be very simple solution:

```
dataDF.columns.levels = [[u'Z', u'B', u'C', u'D', u'E'], [u'100', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'5'], [u'Z', u'II', u'III']]
```

But an error message was displayed:

```
C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: FutureWarning: setting `levels` directly is deprecated. Use set_levels instead
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

It appears that it worked  but does not work anymore. So I used:

```
dataDF.columns.set_levels([['Z', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
                           ['100', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
                           ['Z', 'II', 'III']],
                          [0, 1, 2], inplace=True)
```

Result: `dataDF`

```
Z   B   C   D   E
100 2   3   4   5
Z   II  Z   II  III
0   1   1   1   1   1
1   2   2   2   2   2
2   3   3   3   3   3
3   4   4   4   4   4
4   5   5   5   5   5
```